# Duplicate items from one ComboBox to another in one step

Tags: c#, combobox, items

I have many identical ComboBoxes. At design time, I set the elements of just the first one. At run time, I want to copy the items from the first one to the other ones.

I can easily get the Items from the first one. But I can't assign the Items of the other boxes: ComboBox.Items is read only.

I could use a loop to iterate through all the items and use the ComboBox.Items.Add() method.

Is there a way to do it in one step, without the need to iterate through each item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your current items collection into an array:

```
comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a more complete answer: how to convert Items to a string array.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

1. Convert the items of the first Combobox to array of strings.
2. Use AddRange method: i.e.

   `Combobox.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"A", "B", "C"});`